# MVC 5 Global Resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, global-variables

Okay, I am new to Microsofts MVC architechture, and I am curious if there is a way I can store data that is global to the application and doesn't reside in a database. I have a partial view whose goal is to render out the html for this feed. I need a resource that is global, that can be called from any controller or view. Please help

Comment: `Application` object ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling for an Assembly Resource File.
Here is a link to the MSDN that explains how to create global or local resources files in your project: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to achieve such case:

1. Static properties.
2. Application object.
3. Public resource files.
4. Cache engine.

so on...